# selectizeInput: allowing one element per group

Tags: r, shiny, grouping, selectinput

I have a selectizeInput with some grouped elements with multiple selection. Is there an elegant way (e.g. using the options argument) of allowing just one element per group, so that a whole group will discarded (or disabled) when an element of this specific group is selected?

So far I tried it programmatically, but than the dropdown menu of the selectizeInput will be closed when updating the selectizeInput.

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("selInput", "Default",
                   choices=list(g1 = c(A="A",B="B"), 
                                g2 = c(C="C",D="D")),
                   multiple=T),
    
    selectizeInput("oneElementPerGroup", "One element per group",
                   choices=list(g1 = c(A="A",B="B"), 
                                g2 = c(C="C",D="D")),
                   multiple=T)
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {

    #Removes the corresponding groups of selected items
    observeEvent(input$oneElementPerGroup, ignoreNULL = F, {
        plusChoice <- input$oneElementPerGroup
        names(plusChoice) <- input$oneElementPerGroup
        
        choices <- list(g1 = c(A="A",B="B"), 
                        g2 = c(C="C",D="D"))
        
        if(any(input$oneElementPerGroup %in% c("A", "B"))){
            choices[["g1"]] <- NULL
        }
        if(any(input$oneElementPerGroup %in% c("C", "D"))){
            choices[["g2"]] <- NULL
        }
        choices$we <- plusChoice
        updateSelectizeInput(session,"oneElementPerGroup", 
                             choices = choices,
                             selected=input$oneElementPerGroup)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pickerInput` from {shinyWidgets}. Then we can add a little javascript to do what you want. No server code is needed, very simple. Read more about the `data-max-options` option: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/.

We need to add the limit to each group, not an overall limit, so we can't add it through the `options` argument in `pickerInput`, have to do it in raw HTML or use some js code to inject like what I do.

Be sure your `inputId="pick"` matches the id in the script `#pick`. Rename `pick` to whatever you want.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
        inputId = "pick", label = "Selected",
        choices =list(g1 = c(A="A",B="B"), g2 = c(C="C",D="D")),
        multiple = TRUE
        ),
    tags$script(
        '
        $(function(){
            $("#pick optgroup").attr("data-max-options", "1");
        })
        '
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### updates:

If you need to update, we need to run the script again but from server. We can send js by using {shinyjs}. Imagine an observer triggers the update event.

```r
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
        inputId = "pick", label = "Selected",
        choices =NULL,
        multiple = TRUE
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    observe({
        shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(session, "pick", choices = list(g1 = c(A="A",B="B"), g2 = c(C="C",D="D")))
        observeEvent(once = TRUE, reactiveValuesToList(session$input), {
            runjs('$("#pick optgroup").attr("data-max-options", "1");')
        }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })

    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when I update the pickerInput. Do I have to call the script again somewhere/somehow?
Btw the 'disabled' option for the choicesOpt argument is also helpful.